# Issue with foreground service android 11 and 12

Tags: android, react-native, background, geolocation, location

Any one know how get the location update every seconds. when my device on foreground or background mode.
I am working on Tracking app get the location in every seconds when he is waking on road or traveling whatever.

Actually my app working on version 10 not working on android 11 and 12.
Also searched on google don't found exact answer.

I used this permission:

1. Access background permission,
2. Access Coarse permission.
3. Access Fine Location.
   OR Foreground services for notification

If any one know please let tell me

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problem is app not work in background service. After 5 minutes app is killed on Android 11 and 12 version.

Answer (score 0):

in android 11 or higher the user has to go to app permissions and specifically give them permissions to always take the position in the background. This permission cannot be requested from the app. Only from the phone configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To help protect user privacy, Android 11 (API level 30) introduces limitations to when a foreground service can access the device's location, camera, or microphone. When your app starts a foreground service while the app is running in the background, the foreground service has the following limitations:

Unless the user has granted the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission to your app, the foreground service cannot access location.
The foreground service cannot access the microphone or camera.

Reference link : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#access-restrictions

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the Foreground service for that and add a task in the Foreground service to get a location using geolocation or any other library.

steps to implement:

1. implement foreground service using link library::[1]: https://github.com/Raja0sama/rn-foreground-service.
2. add headless task using geolocation.
3. you will get the location after the app is removed from recent.